# Bash "if ping then else" My else is not working

Tags: macos, bash

I have a bash script that should work based on whether I can ping my network address or not.  There will be instances when this script is ran outside of my network in which case I don't want it to run.  So I put together this

```
if ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.x.x > /dev/null; then
```

When it's in the network, the "then" statement works just fine.  However, whenever I turn off my wireless card and disconnect my ethernet cable to test the "else" my else statement never get's executed.  Is there another way I should be writing this?

Here's the full script;

```
#!/bin/bash

computerid=`/usr/sbin/scutil --get LocalHostName`

# Standard parameters
domain="xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx"                            # fully qualified DNS name of Active Directory Domain
udn="xxxxxx"                                            # username of a privileged network user
password="xxxxxx"                                           # password of a privileged network user
ou="OU=MacOS,DC=xxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx"              # Distinguished name of container for the computer

# Advanced options
alldomains="enable"                 # 'enable' or 'disable' automatic multi-domain authentication
localhome="enable"                  # 'enable' or 'disable' force home directory to local drive
protocol="smb"                              # 'afp' or 'smb' change how home is mounted from server
mobile="enable"                         # 'enable' or 'disable' mobile account support for offline logon
mobileconfirm="disable"             # 'enable' or 'disable' warn the user that a mobile acct will be created
useuncpath="enable"                 # 'enable' or 'disable' use AD SMBHome attribute to determine the home dir
user_shell="/bin/bash"              # e.g., /bin/bash or "none"
preferred="-preferred xxx.xxxxxx.xxx"       # Use the specified server for all Directory lookups and authentication
# (e.g. "-nopreferred" or "-preferred ad.server.edu")
admingroups="xxx\domain admins,xxx\enterprise admins,xxx\teacher98,xxx\ADManagement - Computers,xxx\admin employees"        # These comma-separated AD groups may administer the machine (e.g. "" or "APPLE\mac admins")

### End of configuration

# Delay the login window by unloading the com.apple.loginwindow
# LaunchDaemon in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/

launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.loginwindow.plist


## Wait until all network services are up.
sleep 10

# Check to see if we're in the district
if ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.x.x > /dev/null; then


    #make sure time is set correctly
    ntpdate -u time.xxxxxxx.xxx


    # Activate the AD plugin
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/DirectoryService "Active Directory" "Active"
    plutil -convert xml1 /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.plist
    sleep 5

    # Remove computer from OU
    dsconfigad -f -r -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxx
    sleep 5

    # Bind to AD
    dsconfigad -f -a $computerid -domain $domain -u $udn -p "$password" -ou "$ou"

    # Configure advanced AD plugin options
    if [ "$admingroups" = "" ]; then
        dsconfigad -nogroups
    else
        dsconfigad -groups "$admingroups"
    fi

    dsconfigad -alldomains $alldomains -localhome $localhome -protocol $protocol \
        -mobile $mobile -mobileconfirm $mobileconfirm -useuncpath $useuncpath \
        -shell $user_shell $preferred

    # Restart DirectoryService (necessary to reload AD plugin activation settings)
    killall DirectoryService

    # Add the AD node to the search path
    if [ "$alldomains" = "enable" ]; then
        csp="/Active Directory/All Domains"
    else
        csp="/Active Directory/$domain"
    fi

    # This works in a pinch if the above code does not
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/SearchNodeConfig "Search Node Custom Path Array" -array "/Active Directory/All Domains"
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/SearchNodeConfig "Search Policy" -int 4
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/ContactsNodeConfig "Search Node Custom Path Array" -array "/Active Directory/All Domains"
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/ContactsNodeConfig "Search Policy" -int 4

    plutil -convert xml1 /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/SearchNodeConfig.plist

    ## Remove the script and launchd job. Be sure to delete the script. 
    rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.xxxx.adbind.plist
    rm /usr/local/bin/adbind.bash
    launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.xxxx.adbind.plist

    # Remove the loginwindow delay by loading the com.apple.loginwindow   
    # LaunchDaemon in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/

    launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.loginwindow.plist

    exit 0

else

    echo "District not Available Quitting"

    # Remove the loginwindow delay by loading the com.apple.loginwindow   
    # LaunchDaemon in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/

    launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.loginwindow.plist

fi

exit 1
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How does `ping` behave if you run it on the command line under these conditions?

Comment: $ ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.x.x
PING xxx.xxx.x.x (xxx.xxx.x.x): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host

--- xxx.xxx.x.x ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

Comment: Yes, but what is the exit code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to show my true ignorance, I'm not sure how to produce the exit code.  Is it something simple I can do?  I've been reading the ping man but can't find out how.

Comment: run it, then `if [ $? ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi`

Comment: Put `set -xv` in the top of your program. This will turn on debugging and show you each and every line executed, and how that line is interpolated via the shell before it is executed. Most of the time, your error will jump out at you. It will at least verify that you're executing the `if` statement, then not going to the `else` clause. Not that the `if` statement is getting skipped or that the `else` clause is executed, but doesn't do what you think it should do.

Comment: OK thanks for your patience.  When I check for the exit code like this "ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.x.x > /dev/null
if [ $? ]; then
echo true;
else 
echo false;
fi"  I get a return of true, whether it's on the network or off the network.

Comment: `if [ $? ]`, will always be true. All that does is test if `$?` has output (In that example, it will actually be a syntax error if it doesn't).

Comment: Alright, David.  Your suggestion to use set -xv helped alot but I also had to rem out the launchctl unload statements to watch the script run.  It appears as if the else statement is working, but for some reason it's not executing the "launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.loginwindow.plist"

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a timeout (-W)  `man ping`

Comment: Sorry Nahuel, this didn't help my script.  I appreciate the thought.